# changing the name of type="file" input tag?

Tags: html

i have an input tag...

```
<input type="file" name="upload">
```

for browsing it makes the button vith value `"browse"`(in mozilla)

the question is: how can i change the name of that button? i want it to have the name `"select"` instead of `"browse"`.

Thanks

Comment: i hate things, that seems inpossible!

Comment: @Daniel Vallallo gives you a link that will solve your problem, though it might be more complicated that you want to bother with.

Comment: this site makes impossible things possible, i love it:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the button text of an `<input type="file">` is controlled by the browser, and cannot be changed, as far as I know.

In general, fancy file uploaders are often flash-based. However, if you are ready for a challenge, you may want to check out the following QuirksMode article for a few CSS + JavaScript tricks in this direction:

- [QuirksMode: Styling an input type="file"](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried, but can you set the input to display:none and then use background images?